# PHPExcel, how to display the chart only - not the table data?

Tags: charts, phpexcel

In PHPExcel [33chartcreate-line.php](https://github.com/affinitybridge/phpexcel/blob/master/Tests/33chartcreate-line.php) example creates sheet([screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/4qa9id407/)) that contains table data(A1,D5) and chart.

How to create sheet that will contain only the chart but not the table?

Comment: Put the chart on a sheet on its own, and hide the sheet that contains the data

Comment: @Mark, is there another way? Hiding it will not work for my case(it's a large table, 50+ columns, and I need just small size chart out of it. Also there are other tables on the sheet). Thanks!

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the problem, because I don't see why you can't hide the data sheet. How would you do what you want in MS Excel itself?

Comment: @MarkBaker you are right; My blame, I was looking for something that MS Excel cannot do by itself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Below code draws chart from first line, so hides the table.

```
$chart -> setTopLeftPosition('A1');
```